# Material UI Text Field with type datetime to be of multiple lines

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I would like to have a Material UI component of type: "datetime-local" that is able to be of multiple lines while still having the option to edit the date. This is for the case that the width is not enough and cuts the date text.

The TextField API has an attribute called multiline but this just converts it to: "a textarea element will be rendered instead of an input." So in other words it is no longer editable as a date.

I have the this codesandbox where the case is shown: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ms08e?file=/demo.js (There is a date where the width cuts the text).

Comment: You cannot do that. a possible solution is to reduce the font-size or put each textfield on a single row on small devices.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and idk if you could do it then but you can now:

```
<DateTimePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      multiline: true,
    },
  }}
/>;
```